# How can I generate an XML catalog from my remote Nexus Maven repository?

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype, xmlcatalog

My company hosts its own Maven repository using Sonatype Nexus.  Many of the hosted artifacts were published without using the archetype plugin, and thus are not included in the archetype-catalog.xml file.  Is there a way, either through a Maven command or some feature of Sonatype's software, to generate an XML that describes the content of the repository?  Re-publishing everything would be a huge undertaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CAustin,

The [Sonatype guide to Nexus backups](http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-backup-nexus-configuration-and-repository-artifacts/#.VGFYUfmUfNQ) is probably your best reference. Money quote:

> Luckily, Nexus was designed to use the filesystem to store both
>   configuration and repository data.   This means that backing up your
>   Nexus installation is as easy as configuring an automated backup tool
>   such as amanda or a simple backup script that uses rsync.   There is
>   no database to export or server to suspend for the duration of the
>   backup.  Backing up or restoring a Nexus installation is as easy as
>   copying a set of files.

So simply run `find` command in `sonatype-work/nexus/storage/` directory, e.g.

```
$ find sonatype-work/nexus/ -type f -name pom.xml
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I was hoping for something that utilized the HTTP connection rather than mapping a network drive or connecting with SSH since this would require some extra steps from our IT team, but this is probably a more powerful option in the end.